# Cambiar CultureInfo de Mes a español

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un campo dateTime que me trae el nombre del mes en ingles:

```
var mes = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

en este caso me da el valor de `March`. Lo que quiero hacer es cambiarlo a español

En esta [página](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx) observé que puedo utilizar `es-MX` como CultureInfo, por lo que trato de hacer lo siguiente:

```
 var mes = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo("es-MX"));
```

pero me sale un error que dice:

> Non invocable member 'CultureInfo' cannot be use like a method

Como puedo solucionar este problema? Gracias

Comment: Sólo por curiosidad, ¿Qué idioma tiene tu computadora de desarrollo?

Comment: Ingles. Ya solucioné el problema.En un segundo subola respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para solucionar esto es necesario declarar nuestra cultura antes de utilizarla:

```
 CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
 ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
 var mes = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", ci);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué inicializas dos veces el objeto?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mes = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM",  new CultureInfo("es-MX"));
```

Espero que sea la solución que buscas..

Saludos